# Django static files don't show up on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've nearly got my django project deployed to heroku, but my static files aren't showing up.

```
|--- .git
|--- .gitignore
|--- Procfile
|--- requirements.txt
|--- manage.py
|--- myproj
    |--- __init__.py
    |--- settings.py
    |--- urls.py
    |--- wsgi.py
    |--- templates
         |--- *.html
    |--- static
    |--- media
    |--- static
        |--- js
            |--- *.js
        |--- css
            |--- *.css
    |--- static-only
|--- myapp
```

When I run my project locally, all of my static files are accessed with exit code 200.

However, they are not located when deploying to heroku. collectstatic is successful.

Below is the relevant part of my `settings.py`

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'

# Template location

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "templates"),
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static"),
)
```

Has anyone seen this before?

**EDIT**

`myproj/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
import settings

urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^auth/$', 'myapp.views.auth_view'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'myapp.views.logout'),
    url(r'^loggedin/$', 'myapp.views.loggedin'),
    url(r'invalid/$', 'myapp.views.invalid_login'),
    url(r'^register/', 'myapp.views.register_user'),
    url(r'^register_success/', 'myapp.views.register_success'),
    url(r'^files/', 'myapp.views.files'),
    url(r'^practice/', 'myapp.views.practice'),
    url(r'^download/', 'myapp.views.download'),
    url(r'^listening/', 'myapp.views.listening'),
    url(r'^training/', 'myapp.views.training'),
    url(r'^upload/', 'myapp.views.upload'),
    url(r'^update_user/', 'myapp.views.update_user'),
)
```

Comment: What is the `DEBUG` setting? Have you followed the [instructions for deployment on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)?

Comment: I tried both `DEBUG = True` and `DEBUG = False`. I followed that and it didn't work.

Comment: @erip Your project structure confuse me. Tell `static` folder inside the app or in project root folder ?

Comment: @Raja originally it was within myproj with `templates`, but I moved it around to try different places.

Comment: The way you configured static will not work the way your setting look. Please move static to  corresponding myapp then will see

Comment: @Raja It still doesn't work.

Comment: It will work when you correctly configure. Let we further debug this. Is your project somewhere shall i take look ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT,'show_indexes': False}),
)
```

to the end of my `urls.py`